# Webhook settings and apex class

Tags: apex, api, force.com-sites, setup, webhooks

I'm new to the topic of webhook and also apex, and I'm getting confused when you are making the setting in Salesforce and also the creation of the class.

1. When you are placing the path in the class, is necessary to place/API/etc/etc or you can place a custom one like /mycustompath, and that's it? [image]
2. For the settings in salesforce, in Site Label I tried to place different names, but it displayed that are already in use, this label searches on the internet for the name or in Salesforce? [image]
3. What can be placed at the end of the Default web address? is needs to place the path that I type in the apex class or is it a specific one?

[image]

Can someone help me or explain to me how to make these initial steps for the Webhooks?

Comment: Please check this link https://heysalesforce.org/posts/create-public-api-in-salesforce-using-apex-web-services

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to demonstrate the research you have undertaken and focus on specific technical challenges you face. For example, link to and quote documentation that is not clear for you. As it stands this question doesn't really meet community needs and is likely to be closed without answer. Check on [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) and the standard Salesforce documentation for the details around [custom REST APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm).

Comment: Thx @SarojBera I really appreciate that link, now I understood this topic :D

Comment: see also https://www.logic2020.com/insight/tactical/salesforce-webhook-listener

Answer (score 0):

Gerson,

It seems like you may be trying to set up a salesforce website and have it query your salesforce instance OR trying to create a rest api that can be queried outside? I'm not sure how that will enable webhooks for you.

If you are looking to set up webhooks from Salesforce, I assume you mean that you want to notify an EXTERNAL source when there is a change in Salesforce. You can set one up easily using this guide here: https://jamesward.com/2014/06/30/create-webhooks-on-salesforce-com/

You can also look at the github repo for this and see the exact implementation this person took.

One thing to note is that the approach lacks a bit of security verification though, if you're comfortable using a free managed solution for salesforce webhooks with a 1-click installation experience, check out Fusebit: https://developer.fusebit.io/docs/salesforce-events

DISCLAIMER: I work at Fusebit.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! If my research is correct, you are affiliated with Fusebit. From a section of the SFSE Help Center (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion): *"Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers**."* (emphasis added) Please edit your answer to add any disclosure(s). And please spend some time getting a feel of the culture and expectations of a site you are new to before posting.

Comment: oops! was not aware of the need for a disclaimer - added that in now, thanks for the heads up!